# Importing to Android Studios, Manifest files "cannot resolve symbol" for my Activities/application tags

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-manifest

I imported an android project from Eclipse to Android Studios and I started with the problem that when I would edit the run configurations it would say that my default activity wasn't an activity or sub class

[image: Config error]

So, I then assumed that there was a problem when declaring my file as an activity in the manifest file. Looks like I'm right but how do I fix it?

[image: YUNOWORK]

The manifest file is part of the Module PimsPoints and the PimsLib has all the /res and the Application Class but it looks like Studios is confused at where its supposed to look, and I don't know my way around this program (or android development) enough to fix this one.

Comment: What does your build.gradle look like ?

Comment: When I exported to a gradle project from eclipse it made me 4 build.gradle files. one at the root level and one for each of my modules (PimsLib, PimsPoints, PimsDev). the root level one is pretty empty, just as repositories{meavenCentral()} and  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }

Comment: The pimslib one has dependencies and sourceSets
sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        } instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

Comment: Hmmm looks sourceSets are properly set.  What happens if you press the 5th icon from the right, the one with gradle icon and blue down arrow ?  Any errors ?

Comment: Looks like it worked, at the bottom status bar it says "Gradle build finished in 7 sec"

Comment: Well, @Ahufford! I had the same problem with this, and I had pressed the **icon** (5th icon from the right with blue down arrow), but the errors still comes. How did you fixed the problem? I need your help! And here are the some informations of the log:  **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter**